# How to replace svn's sub directory vendor branch with git's subtree merge

Tags: git, zend-framework, git-svn, vendor-branch

The old process was the normal [svn vendor branch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html), however I only ever copied a sub-directory to the main codebase. So for:

```
vendors/Zend_Framework/current/library/Zend
```

was copied to:

```
trunk/library/Zend
```

I'd then add the new version, tag it and merge the differences between the two library/Zend folders into trunk/library/Zend

How do I do this in Git?

My first thoughts where to create a git clone of the subversion repo using git-svn and then use subtree merge, but I'm not sure how that can be achieved when the target is actually a sub directory of the external repo. To be honest, I'd rather not merge in all the other directories as well, such as documentation and tests.

Am I going to have to create my own git repo based on the [sub directory of a tag](http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.10.7/library/Zend/), subtree merge that in, and then manually update that git repo by downloading the new version on top, dealing with new dirs, deleted dirs/files manually myself?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use git-svn. I would use svn to keep your `vendors/Zend_Framework/` up-to-date and then use [svn export](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re10.html) to put the `library/Zend` directory where you need it. If you have made changes to the Zend Framework files, consider having a library/YourNamespaceHere directory and putting your custom changes there.